# how to place two located latitude and longitude place same time in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cordova, jquery-mobile, geolocation

We need to displayed two location latitude and longitude at a time.We have two set of latitude and longitude like this

```
[{"Longitude":"17.4954","Lattitude":"78.2960","UserID":3},{"Longitude":"17.3616","Lattitude":"78.4747","UserID":3}]
```

My problem is it's pin show only last longitude and latitude only We code this

```
$(all).each(function () {
    alert(this.Longitude);
    alert(this.Lattitude);


    debugger;
     directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(this.Longitude, this.Lattitude);

    debugger;
    var myOptions = {
        zoom:7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: mapCenter


    }

    debugger;
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  //  directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directions"));  

// marker will be displayed on the lat long position
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

position:mapCenter,
map: map
});
});
```

all variable get data  dynamic it's means some time it's come 10 location also
Any one tell me What wrong in my code.and Please guide me.

Comment: you want to place 2 markers?

Comment: @Ethaan YES i have 10 points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%;height:100%; position:absolute;"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var all=[{"Longitude":"17.3616","Lattitude":"78.4747","UserID":3},{"Longitude":"17.4954","Lattitude":"78.2960","UserID":3}];
var map;
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
$(all).each(function (key, value) {

    if(key == 0){
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
          zoom: 6,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(this.Lattitude, this.Longitude),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
    }       

   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(this.Lattitude, this.Longitude),
        map: map
   });

   var content = this.Lattitude+", "+this.Longitude;
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, key) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(content);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
   })(marker, key));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have this array

```
var markersArray = [{"Longitude":"17.4954","Lattitude":"78.2960","UserID":3},{"Longitude":"17.3616","Lattitude":"78.4747","UserID":3}]
```

so if you run `console.log(markersArray.length)`, you will get this output

```
2
```

At this point we are okay?

Well now we need a [functions](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp) with a [for loop](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) to create the markers based on that `markersArray`

a function like this.

```
function createMarkers(){
  for(var i = 0 ; i <markersArray.length ; i++) {
      lat = markersArray[i].Lattitude;
      long = markersArray[i].longitude;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
        map: map,
        icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png'
      });
    }
}
```

**explain where do I need to place your code in my code**

You need to place this code inside the `initializeMap()` function(or whatever function name you use to init the map).

`createMarkers()` <-- like this

Comment: thanks for reply.I am new this can you explain where do I need to place your code in my code

Comment: can you please upload you code inside a jsFiddle, but look in resume, you have a nested object `{"Longitude":"17.4954","Lattitude":"78.2960","UserID":3},{"Longitude":"17.3616","Lattitude":"78.4747","UserID":3}`
so just create a function to create markers based on that nested object, but like i say please upload the code inside a [jsFiddle](jsfiddle.net)